# Create X-Y plots in C

Tags: c, user-interface, graph, plot

I'm planning on doing a small project involving ECG signals. I am currently getting ECG signals via a COM port and recording these in a txt file using C programming.

My next step is to be able to plot all those data points in real-time. Can this be done using C programming? If not, I do not mind collecting a sample that is 2 minutes long and then plotting those data points.

After that, I want to be able to take the FFT of the time-domain data and be able to plot the frequency plot.

My end goal is to design a GUI using C, that shows a person the real-time EEG waveform as well as the frequency plot.

I did make another post and was advised to try:

- RRDTool (http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) : However, this doesn't seem to be a straightforward implementation for C.
- OpenGL Utility Toolkit (http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) : This seems to be really powerful for generating 3D plots. However, I couldn't find helpful guides simplifying 2D plot implementations
- KST : http://kst-plot.kde.org/ , This was the most interesting software. I've played around with it a bit and like it's simplicity. It also allows me to get FFT data. However, I'm not sure how to connect it with my end goal of having the GUI since it is a seperate program.

If someone could recommend C based implementation and some tutorials/sample code to go along with it that would be great. Additionally, advice on other alternatives to reach my end-goal would also be much appreciated !

Comment: Have you considered prototyping in another language first, such as Python?

Comment: Ignacio : I haven't considered doing that. Solely if I have it working in Python, I might not be able to get things working in C due to compatibility issues. So I thought of starting code development with C itself.

Comment: previous SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884849/what-can-i-use-for-real-time-plotting-graphing-in-c

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). It's more 2d based and easier to learn than OpenGL, written in C and quite powerful.

If you want you can first try out SDL in Python using [pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html).

Answer (score 0):

Qt http://qt.nokia.com/products/ has a plot widget that you could use ... and has language bindings for many languages

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/). Works with many languages, including C, on all the common desktop operating systems (Mac, Windows, Linux, Unix). There are [quite a few examples](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php), and most (if not all) examples are available in a number of different languages.